# AWS deployment of Asp.net-Core application using JavascriptServices(AspnetCore.NodeServices)

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, asp.net-core

I need to deploy an web application on AWS-Beanstalk that uses ASP.NET JavascriptServices for using NodeJS modules. The purpose of the application is to generate server side JS charts, I followed the below article

https://gunnarpeipman.com/aspnet/aspnet-core-node-d3js

So this application uses both Asp.net Core and NodeJS(node modules 'JSDOM', 'SVG2PNG' and 'D3'). The application is working fine in local machine however when deployed on AWS other pages work fine when I access the page using Node services I get an Exception(the exception is not displayed).

Below is the code used in Controller to access the Node module in javascript file,

```
public async Task<IActionResult> About([FromServices] INodeServices nodeServices)
{
    var options = new { width = 900, height = 900 };
    var data = new[] {
    new { label = "Abulia", count = 10 },
    new { label = "Betelgeuse", count = 20 },
    new { label = "Cantaloupe", count = 30 },
    new { label = "Dijkstra", count = 40 }
    };
    ViewData["ChartImage"] = await nodeServices.InvokeAsync<string>("Noded3Chart.js", options, data);

    return View();
}
```

I need an guidance on the below questions

1. Can we deploy this type of application on AWS that uses two technologies Asp.Net and NodeJS, if yes any lead will greatly help.
2. How to install the dependent modules such as SVG2PNG, JSDOM etc. in this type of setup on AWS.